# How to get docker oracle container ip into the java application using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The below code iam using in docker-compose:

```
integration_test:

  image: service:1.0.0

  volumes:
    - .:/service

  links:
   - oracle_container
  # used volumes_from as workaround to wait until the following containers to start

  volumes_from:
   - oracle_container

  container_name: integration_test

  tty: true

  environment:
    USER: go

  command: ["mvn clean install -DskipTests"]

oracle_container:

  image: inmage_name:1.0.0

  container_name: oracle_container

  ports:
    - "49161:1521"
```

I want to make the both containers talk application-->oracle

Both containers are running in same machine and i used the below jdbc string to connect the oracle via application,

jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:49161/xe

But iam not able to connect the oracle and its throwing SQLRecoverable Exception.

As per my understanding, this comes under Docker Networking and I have used links to connect two containers. but this issue is with the connection string and more specifically ip of the oracle container.

Can someone help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle_container:1521/xe
```

In docker-compose each container can reach other on their service name of the container name. You should not used the host ports instead the container port only